# If $3x+4y+5z=1$, for positive real $x$, $y$, $z$, then find the minimum integer value of $\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My question is about minimum value of a sum, here is the question:

> $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all positive real numbers and
> $$3x+4y+5z=1$$
> Find the minimum integer value of the sum of the reciprocals of $x, y$, and $z$.

I think i am going to use AM-HM inequality because i need harmonic mean to obtain the sum of the reciprocals of x, y and z but how can i realize this idea?..

Thanks for your help

Comment: No personal work on this issue ?

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456100/what-is-the-minimum-value-of

Answer (score 1):

As Macavity pointed out, we shall use the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality.

It states that $$(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2)(\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2) \geq (\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i)^2$$

Here, we let $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2 = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2 = 1 = 3x + 4y + 5z$

Notice that multiplying the harmonic part by 1 wouldn't change anything, so we do exactly that and then use CS to get

$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z} \geq (\sqrt3 + 2 + \sqrt5)^2 $$

From here, we know that the minimum of the harmonic thing is $(\sqrt3 + 2 + \sqrt5)^2$. Now one could simply plug this expression into some calculator and get that the maximum integer possible, i.e., the floor of the expression, is $36$.

Comment: @Macavity I'm sorry OP changed the question after me answering the older one. Check the edit logs to confirm. I will soon edit my answer.

Comment: You've just showed the best integer lower bound is at least $36$, not $35$… That's possible with $(x,y,z)=(\frac19,\frac1{12},\frac1{15})$ which shows it is the minimum.

Comment: I'm sorry thank you for pointing out that typo